# Two new urls but second one missing path variable in Cypress

Tags: javascript, url, cypress

Maybe a bit difficult to explain but I have the following issue. I have created a link and Cypress wants to click it, but it seems to click it twice. The second time the path variable is missing (the ID of an incident) and now it stores 'undefined' as incident ID, while the ID is '458868'

Does anyone why it calls this URL twice and why the second time the incident ID is missing in the URL?

The step definition is:

`cy.get('.html-link').click({force:true});`

Thanks!!
[image]

Comment: Please add your entire test

Comment: sorry, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have solved the issue:

@Fody said to add a wait in the step.

```
cy.get('.html-link').wait(1000).click({force:true});
```

Although i'm not a fan of waits, in this case it seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: I suggested the wait as a debugging check, but if it's the quickest way to resolve the problem, that's ok.  To solve without a wait, you can use `.intercept()` to ensure your url has 5 parts.

Comment: I'm working on it, but it takes a little more time to let you know if it works. But i think i have something: cy.get().intercept('incidents/**).click();

Where the ** are the incidentID's

Comment: @Fody .intercept() yields null so i cannot use it like i want to, so i used it separately but the issue remained. The hard wait seems to be more effective.
I used the .intercept() this way:
`
cy.get('.html-link').intercept('/incidents/**);
cy.get('.html-link').click();
`

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely the `.click()` is happening twice. More likely the 2nd call to `/incidents` is just part of the page load, same as call to `/incidents` ***before*** the click.

To check it out, put in a long wait before clicking, see if the order of logging changes.

**"it stores 'undefined' as incident ID"** - please clarify where it's being stored - on the server, or in the test via an intercept?

If you are using an intercept, it's matcher needs to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, we store part of the URL (the needed Incident ID) in a variable, using           
 
`getAndSaveVoorvalId: () => cy.location('pathname')                     
  .then(url => {
   const splittedUrl = url.split('/');
   return World.settestMainId(splittedUrl[5]);
  })   `

And sometimes the test passes and the second call has the incident ID in the URL. So i'm not sure why this fails sometimes.